# Rollback not working in jdbc spring programatic transaction

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, oracle11g

Im unable to get a rollback working in my spring (3.0.5) jdbc application, running on Oracle 11.2

When I throw `NoClassesException` in the Controller below the row inserted by updatedB() remains in the dB.
I think this is because autoCommit is on (by default) in my dataSource so the commit has already happened and the rollback obviously doesn't work, 
but I thought the Spring `DataSourceTransactionManager` handled all this and enforced the rollback?

Interestingly, when i turn autoCommit off in my dataSource ie comment in the :

```
"defaultAutoCommit" value="false"
```

and call the commit explicity myself ie comment in:

```
this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().commit();
```

nothing happens ie the row is not commited at all,so it looks like i've done something stupid.
If someone could please point out this mistake I would be very gratefull

My code is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [] configList ={"database.xml","spring.xml"};

        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(configList);
        cont = (Controller)ctx.getBean("controller");
        cont.transactionTest();
}
```

// Controller , called from Main()

```
public class Controller {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    public void transactionTest()
    {       
        int retCode=0;


        try {
            retCode = updatedB("param1","param2");
            //this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().commit();
            throw new NoClassesException(); 
        }catch (NoClassesException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "2 patents ");
        }
    }

    public int updatedB(String param1,String param2 ) 
    {
        int stat = 0;

        stat = this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO myTable"
                                + "(param1,param2)"
                                + " VALUES(?,?)"  , 
                new Object[] { param1,param2});

        return stat;
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

```
public class NoClassesException extends RuntimeException  {

    public NoClassesException() {
        super("Rolled back ");
    }
}
```

and my spring.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">


    <bean id="controller" class="Controller">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="transaction*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="NoClassesException" />
            <tx:method name="update*" propagation="SUPPORTS" />
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>



    <aop:config>    
        <aop:pointcut id="myMethods" expression="execution(* *..Controller.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="myMethods" />
    </aop:config>



    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and my database.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">



    <bean id="dataConfigPropertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="2" />

        <property name="url" value="my connection details" />
        <property name="username" value="xxx" />
        <property name="password" value="xxx" />
        <!-- <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" /> -->
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Why you catch NoClassesException ?.. remove the sysout and try again

Comment: You are throwing and catching and swallowing the exception. The `DataSourceTransactionManager` never sees the exception and will commit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when I remove the try catch the row is still committed. The stack trace is:Exception in thread "main" NoClassesException: Rolled back 
 at Controller.transactionTest(Controller.java:34)
 at MainDS.main(MainDS.java:43)

Comment: After suggestions from M Denium, Xstian and Sezin Karli
I changed the call in Main() from :
cont.transactionTest();
to
cont.mainTest();

and added 

public void mainTest()
{
 try{
  transactionTest();
 }catch (NoClassesException e){
  System.out.println(e.getMessage() );
 } 
}

into the Controller to allow the transaction to complete before I catch the NoClassesException() but the row was still inserted into the dB.
Note - I tried to edit the original post to include these changes but the editor kept complaining about format errors.
Any other suggestions extremely welcome.

Comment: I checked the state of the transaction before updateDb() is called using TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() and it returned false. But why is the transaction not active? Is my pointcut expression wrong? Note im using the default package in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be updated such as

```
 public void transactionTest()
    {       
        int retCode=0;

            retCode = updatedB("param1","param2");
            //this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().commit();
            throw new NoClassesException(); 

    }

    public int updatedB(String param1,String param2 ) 
    {
        int stat = 0;

        stat = this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO myTable"
                                + "(param1,param2)"
                                + " VALUES(?,?)"  , 
                new Object[] { param1,param2});

        return stat;
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sezin. I tried this but the row is still committed. The stack trace is Exception in thread "main" NoClassesException: Rolled back 
 at Controller.transactionTest(Controller.java:34)
 at MainDS.main(MainDS.java:43)